# How to mask existing datas in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage

I have an azure table storage with thousands of records. I need to mask certain sensitive data eg :
CustomerName : Tim Captain as T***** C****
BSBNumber :0342 8765 as ***8765

Comment: hi @Jen. edit and provide more information. what you tried and expecting?

Comment: Is your aim to actually update the data in table or just have a dynamic masking? Table storage doesn't allow dynamic masking like Azure SQL does.

Comment: @AnupamChand  Update the data in the table. Does Adf allows to do the transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Unlike Azure SQL databases/synapse which provides the functionality of Dynamic data masking, Azure table storage doesnt have any such functionality.
In case if you need masking aspect, you would have to have a custom logic while loading data to mask data during ingestion and based on access need use a reverse logic to unmask while extracting

Comment: Is there any other way I can transform the existing data.Does Adf allow it?